GPU driver is missing on Lubuntu 24.04LTS
I'm new to ubuntu family and Linux at all so here's my case:
I'm using Lubuntu 24.04 LTS on Thinkpad Z61m and while I'm running for example 'google-chrome' in terminal, then it gives me:
r300: driver missing
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_drv_video.so init failed
r300: driver missing
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so init failed
I have tried few thing, for example 'show' path to this file, reinstall 'mesa-va-drivers' and update packages, but nothing worked. I want to solve this issue, because my UI on chrome is buggy right now an I cannot use it normally. From what I understand there's no official support for my [AMD/ATI] RV515/M54 Mobility Radeon X1400, but I wonder if it's an issue only on newest LTS version, or if I reinstall my Lubuntu OS on 22.04 LTS version that could help? Or is there a way to solve this on newest version of Lubuntu?

You mention Lubuntu 22.04 LTS, but I don't know what kernel you're using as you've not said. Lubuntu 22.04 LTS was a long term support release, meaning there was kernel stack choice, with flavors the default stack was chosen by the install media used & you've not said what that was, so re-installing 22.04 now may actually meaning changing your kernel stack (or leaving it the same as I don't know what you're using except Lubuntu 22.04). Lubuntu 22.04 LTS using HWE is using the 24.04 LTS GA kernel; so maybe the same or different to your current kernel.

Sure! Here's some additional information 6.8.0-41-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
